# Updating database using pypyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, python-3.x, pypyodbc

I am facing challenge in updating Database using pypyodbc module.
Not getting any error, code is successfully executed; but SQL-Server DB is not updated.
Fetching from DB is happening.

Please check:

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL SERVER};Server=ser;Database=db;uid=uname;pwd=pass')

cursor=connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("declare @today as date;set @today = convert(varchar,getdate(),101);Update dbo.Credentials_Mst Set Password='qwerty',lastModifiedOn=@today,ModifiedBy='abcd' where Username='abc';")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit your changes. Add this line:

```
connection.commit()
```

After you do `cursor.execute(...)`.

If you don't `commit` before closing the connection, you will lose all of your changes.